# Getting Error:Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT
 LEFT(DateName( Month, TRIPDATE),3 ) + ' ' + RIGHT(DateName( Year, TRIPDATE),2 ) AS [MonthYear],
 SUM(isnull(cast(TOTALFREIGHT as float),0)) AS FreightAmount 
FROM OFFLINETRANS 
Group By DateName( Month, TRIPDATE ), DateName( Year, TRIPDATE ) 
ORDER BY max(TRIPDATE)
```

Comment: What is your expected result format? Is `May 16` ?

Comment: Could you please provide some of the strings? I just want to see if it is in a correct format.

Comment: Yes I want In May 16 but in my Table tripdate is '16/05/2016'

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in SQL? This is something that you'd want to do in your presentation layer surely.

Comment: Ok. As far as i know, SQL-Server doesn't use regional date formats. So you would have to try it with the standard format which is yyyy-mm-dd,  '2016-05-16'.

Comment: SQL Server does support regional datetime formating. Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928(v=sql.120).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert your date/datetime column, something like this:

```
SELECT
 LEFT( DATENAME( MONTH, CONVERT(datetime, TRIPDATE, 103))
 ,3 ) + ' ' + RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, convert(datetime, TRIPDATE, 103)),2 ) AS [MonthYear],
 SUM(ISNULL(cast(TOTALFREIGHT as float),0)) AS FreightAmount 
FROM OFFLINETRANS 
Group By  LEFT( DATENAME( MONTH, CONVERT(datetime, TRIPDATE, 103)) ,3 ) + ' ' + RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, convert(datetime, TRIPDATE, 103)),2 )
ORDER BY max(TRIPDATE)
```

EDIT: do not edit my answer, if you still got issues, edit your own question. If the new issues are not related to the original post, create a new question instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [MonthYear],SUM(CAST(FreightAmount AS DECIMAL(18,2))) As FreightAmount
FROM (
 SELECT LEFT(DateName(Month, TRIPDATE), 3) + ' ' + RIGHT(DateName(Year, TRIPDATE), 2) AS [MonthYear] ,SUM(TRIPCOST) AS FreightAmount ,max(TRIPDATE) AS UsedForOrder
   FROM TRANSVIEW GROUP BY DateName(Month, TRIPDATE) ,DateName(Year, TRIPDATE)

UNION ALL
 SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, TRIPDATE, 103)), 3) + ' ' + RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, convert(DATETIME, TRIPDATE, 103)), 2) AS [MonthYear] ,SUM(ISNULL(cast(TOTALFREIGHT AS FLOAT), 0)) AS FreightAmount ,max(CONVERT(DATETIME, TRIPDATE, 103)) AS UsedForOrder FROM OFFLINETRANS GROUP BY LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, TRIPDATE, 103)), 3) + ' ' + RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, convert(DATETIME, TRIPDATE, 103)), 2)

) AS A GROUP BY [MonthYear] ORDER BY max(UsedForOrder)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.